# Store ArrayList in Android after app closes

Tags: android

I have an ArrayList of Strings from which I am drawing a ListView. In the app, the user can add items to the ArrayList, causing an item to be displayed on the ListView. While the app is running, the ArrayList retains its items, but after a reboot (or any other time when the app stops) the items are lost. I've read about internal, external, and SQLite storage, but I couldn't get internal nor external storage to work, and I know nothing about SQLite and the app is due Friday. Is there a better implementation of saving? I've attached a complete copy of the code without any storage methods for review.

Thanks.

http://www.mediafire.com/?tf8093g39jv0f61 <-- code

Comment: try to post your code on pastie or pastebin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can go for the Serializable idea refer the following links you may get a idea

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html

and

http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_Serialization_Example_%28Java%29

Answer (score 4):

Use the preferences implementation to save the `ArrayList<String>`. In the `onPause` method use this:

```
ArrayList<String> tobesaved = getData(); // fetch the data
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
edit.putStringSet("SAVEDATA", new HashSet<String>(tobesaved));
edit.commit();
```

and then you can fetch it in the `onResume` method:

```
ArrayList<String> retrieved = new ArrayList<String>(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).getStringSet("SAVEDATA", new HashSet<String>()));
```

EDIT: I didn't get a chance to look at your code: mediafire tried to open some popup on my browser so I quickly closed the tab, but that should work for you. Try and perhaps use gist (at http://gist.github.com) or  pastebin (at http://pastebin.com/) instead to share longer code sequences.

Comment: I don't think that the preferences manager is meant to store large amounts of information.

Comment: He never said he was storing large amounts of information. He said he had an ArrayList of Strings to store.

Comment: Sorry, I'm remembering the MediaFire of 2008, when it was actually good. Now I win free iPad 2s every other second.

Comment: Haha. Have you EVER met anyone who ACTUALLY won?

Comment: Yeah! He had to fork out 500 dollars, though.

Comment: HAHAHAHA. That is winning? You mean he bought an iPad.

Comment: HAHAHAHAHAHA. That's even funnier: 2 people paid for it, not one.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<String> tobesaved = getData(); // fetch the data
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
edit.putStringSet("SAVEDATA", new HashSet<String>(tobesaved));
edit.commit();

ArrayList<String> retrieved = new ArrayList<String>(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).getStringSet("SAVEDATA", new HashSet<String>()));
```

This Code works, but I have my Arraylist sorted alphabetically. This hashSet messes up the alphabetical organizations of my strings. . . Anyone can make this answer, great to PERFECT? By making ArrayList save and load with the same order??

Comment: use `collections.sort` on retrieved arraylist